# Is there a version of MM_validateForm that works with pre-populated form fields?

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

Is there a version of the standard DreamWeaver `MM_validateForm` JavaScript function that takes into consideration pre-populated titles-as-values of form fields? Such as

```
<input type="text" name="fname" value="Enter your first name" />
```

which is displayed in a lighter grey color or something. Since this value is already filled, the validation routine passes, which is not correct. How do I fix this?

I don't use DreamWeaver much, so I don't know where to look exactly.

Comment: Which version of MM_validateForm are you using? http://lab.artlung.com/mm_validateform/

Comment: it says v4.0. it's in a file i got from another coder. anyway, i think i got it sorted..

Comment: Cool. I suppose you could answer your own question then, or delete your question. Or just leave it I suppose.

Comment: I simply wrote another function that turns unfilled values to null and I call it before MM_formValidate. I'm not proud of it, but it does the job.

    function AA_preValidateForm() {
        var e;
        e = document.forms[0].elements['fname'];
        if (e.value == 'Enter your first name') e.value = '';
        ...
    }

And on the submit button:

    <input type="submit name="submitbutton" onclick="AA_preValidateForm(); MM_validateForm('name','','R',...)" />

Also an AA_resetForm func.

I'll leave this question open to see if anyone else can come up with a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the empty arguments of the MM_validateForm() call.
Change the call to `MM_validateForm('name','Enter your first name','R',...)`.
Change the function `MM_validateForm()` to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Version 4.0
function MM_validateForm() { //v4.0
  var i,p,q,nm,test,num,min,max,errors='',args=MM_validateForm.arguments;
  for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3) { test=args[i+2]; val=MM_findObj(args[i]);
    if (val) { nm=val.name; val=val.value; if (val!="" && val!=args[i+1]) {
      if (test.indexOf('isEmail')!=-1) { p=val.indexOf('@');
        if (p<1 || p==(val.length-1)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain an e-mail address.\n';
      } else if (test!='R') {
        if (isNaN(val)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number.\n';
        if (test.indexOf('inRange') != -1) { p=test.indexOf(':');
          min=test.substring(8,p); max=test.substring(p+1);
          if (val<min || max<val) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number between '+min+' and '+max+'.\n';
    } } } else if (test.charAt(0) == 'R') errors += '- '+nm+' is required.\n'; }
  } if (errors) alert('The following error(s) occurred:\n'+errors);
  document.MM_returnValue = (errors == '');
}
</script>
```

In short. Change line

```
if (val) { nm=val.name; if ((val=val.value)!="") {
```

to

```
if (val) { nm=val.name; val=val.value; if (val!="" && val!=args[i+1]) {
```